# Thread not applying properly to defined Module

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a module that generates the `n`th Taylor polynomial for a function:

```
taylor[n_, a_] := 
 Module[{terms = {f[0]}}, 
  Do[AppendTo[
    terms, (D[f[x], {x, i}] /. x -> a)/Factorial[i]*(x - a)^i], {i, 1,
     n}]; Return[Plus @@ terms]]
```

Now, I want to call this function such that it generates a list of polynomials. This worked fine with a singular argument and `Map`ing it over a `Range`. However, in trying to `Thread` the module like so:

```
Thread[taylor[Range[7], 0]]
```

I get an error that

> Iterator {i,1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}} does not have appropriate bounds.

i.e., `n` is not being evaluated like I thought it would be, like:

```
{taylor[1,0], taylor[2,0], ...}
```

I could change the implementation of the module, but I do not know why `Thread` is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see if it does what you want

```
taylor[n_, a_] := Module[{terms = {f[0]}}, 
  Do[AppendTo[terms, (D[f[x], {x, i}] /. x -> a)/Factorial[i]*(x - a)^i], {i, 1,n}]; 
  Return[Plus @@ terms]]
Thread[g[{1,2,3},0]]/.g->taylor
```

which returns

```
{f[0] + x*f'[0],
 f[0] + x*f'[0] + x^2*f''[0]/2,
 f[0] + x*f'[0] + x^2*f''[0]/2 + x^3*f'''[0]/6}
```

What that is doing is all the threading without invoking the way that Module evaluates arguments and once that is finished then handing it to Module to complete. Just make certain that you haven't defined `g` before you do this.

Check all this very carefully before you depend on it.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you very much.